# Qiskit unable to transpile the circuit for Rigetti Aspen M 1 on AWS

Tags: qaoa, transpile, amazon-braket, rigetti

I am trying to run a Qiskit QAOA algorithm on AWS Rigetti Aspen M 1 Backend using qiskit braket provider. However qiskit is not able to properly transpile the circuit

```
optimizer = COBYLA(maxiter=50)
provider = AWSBraketProvider()
backend = QuantumInstance(
    provider.get_backend("Aspen-M-1"),
    shots=1024,
    seed_transpiler=algorithm_globals.random_seed,
    seed_simulator=algorithm_globals.random_seed,
)
qaoa = QAOA(
    reps=p,
    expectation=cvar_exp,
    optimizer=optimizer,
    quantum_instance=backend,
    callback=store_intermediate_result,
)
ckt=qaoa.construct_circuit([1.0,1.5],qubit_op)
ckt[0].draw()
transpiled_circuit = transpile(
    ckt[0], 
    backend=provider.get_backend("Aspen-M-1"), 
    #seed_transpiler=42
)
transpiled_circuit.draw(idle_wires=False, fold=-1)
```

leads to the following error:

```
This backend's operations: h,id,p,rx,ry,rz,s,sdg,t,tdg,x,y,z only apply to a subset of qubits. Using this property to get 'basis_gates' for the transpiler may potentially create invalid output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-94170a3bccca> in <module>
     40 transpiled_circuit = transpile(
     41     ckt[0],
---> 42     backend=provider.get_backend("Aspen-M-1"),
     43     #seed_transpiler=42
     44 )

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.py in transpile(circuits, backend, basis_gates, inst_map, coupling_map, backend_properties, initial_layout, layout_method, routing_method, translation_method, scheduling_method, instruction_durations, dt, approximation_degree, timing_constraints, seed_transpiler, optimization_level, callback, output_name, unitary_synthesis_method, unitary_synthesis_plugin_config, target)
    302 
    303     # Transpile circuits in parallel
--> 304     circuits = parallel_map(_transpile_circuit, list(zip(circuits, transpile_args)))
    305 
    306     end_time = time()

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/tools/parallel.py in parallel_map(task, values, task_args, task_kwargs, num_processes)
    127         return []
    128     if len(values) == 1:
--> 129         return [task(values[0], *task_args, **task_kwargs)]
    130 
    131     Publisher().publish("terra.parallel.start", len(values))

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/compiler/transpiler.py in _transpile_circuit(circuit_config_tuple)
    388 
    389     result = pass_manager.run(
--> 390         circuit, callback=transpile_config["callback"], output_name=transpile_config["output_name"]
    391     )
    392 

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py in run(self, circuits, output_name, callback)
    220             return circuits
    221         if isinstance(circuits, QuantumCircuit):
--> 222             return self._run_single_circuit(circuits, output_name, callback)
    223         if len(circuits) == 1:
    224             return self._run_single_circuit(circuits[0], output_name, callback)

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passmanager.py in _run_single_circuit(self, circuit, output_name, callback)
    275         """
    276         running_passmanager = self._create_running_passmanager()
--> 277         result = running_passmanager.run(circuit, output_name=output_name, callback=callback)
    278         self.property_set = running_passmanager.property_set
    279         return result

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py in run(***failed resolving arguments***)
    122         for passset in self.working_list:
    123             for pass_ in passset:
--> 124                 dag = self._do_pass(pass_, dag, passset.options)
    125 
    126         circuit = dag_to_circuit(dag)

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py in _do_pass(self, pass_, dag, options)
    155             # Run the pass itself, if not already run
    156             if pass_ not in self.valid_passes:
--> 157                 dag = self._run_this_pass(pass_, dag)
    158 
    159                 # update the valid_passes property

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/runningpassmanager.py in _run_this_pass(self, pass_, dag)
    209             # Measure time if we have a callback or logging set
    210             start_time = time()
--> 211             pass_.run(FencedDAGCircuit(dag))
    212             end_time = time()
    213             run_time = end_time - start_time

~/anaconda3/envs/Braket/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/transpiler/passes/utils/check_gate_direction.py in run(self, dag)
     44         """
     45         self.property_set["is_direction_mapped"] = True
---> 46         edges = self.coupling_map.get_edges()
     47         trivial_layout = Layout.generate_trivial_layout(*dag.qregs.values())
     48         if self.target is None:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_edges'
```

Similar error occurs when I try to directly get results by

```
result = qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(qubit_op)
```

The code works fine with other hardware, it seems only Rigetti has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Investigating a bit, this looks like it's due to the fact that the Rigetti device's operations aren't all global (there are certain qubits/pairs on which a gate may not be supported). As a result, Qiskit adds a [gate direction check](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/a0b9a846f93a1e580c876b8fb37ae5d10436f594/qiskit/transpiler/preset_passmanagers/level1.py#L368) to the transpiler passes. However, the direction check relies on the coupling map, which isn't populated by the Qiskit-Braket provider. This looks like it's worth raising an issue for in the repo!